# Travis Failing Due to 'require' file LoadError after bundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

```
    /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby -I/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/lib:/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-support-3.4.1/lib /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.4.2/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
    /home/travis/build/jmoon90/seat_geek/lib/seat_geek.rb:13:in `require': cannot load such file -- seat_geek/taxonomies/tree (LoadError). 
The command "bundle exec rake" exited with 1.
```

I'm setting up Travis CI for my [SeatGeek wrapper gem](https://github.com/jmoon90/seat_geek). However, when the CI builds, it bundles correctly, but when it runs the rake tasks, it fails saying it can not load such file.

I'm not sure why that is the case because I make it available in the [master file](https://github.com/jmoon90/seat_geek/blob/master/lib/seat_geek.rb#L13-L16).

It's weird to me that the `seat_geek/query/` folders aren't blowing up before that.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Travis expects the path to be all lower case. The problem was Github did not update my folder name from `Taxonomies/concerts` to `taxonomies/concerts` even after I've made the change and pushed it up.

Github doesn't seem to care if it's uppercase or not. So I had to change the folder name to `taxonomiess` and push that up. Then after that change it back to `taxonomies` with lower case.